# Angular Drag and Drop from table to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

I have two tables. Table A has more data than Table B. In the JSON data structure that I am using for table A - I am not showing all of the data in table A, as it's reserved for Table B. Basically what I want to do, is drag and drop a row from table A to Table B, but when the drop is complete, the data looks completely different from when I started dragging from A. Lets say I'm not displaying object.colorRed in Table A but the data is there. I then move that row to Table B and now I can view object.colorRed.

**What really needs to happen is a row from Table A needs to be split into two. Dividing the data and placing it in two rows in Table B.** I'm not sure how to go about this.

-- Angular 4

Thanks

Comment: referring this may help - https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do something similar with one of my Angular projects, and use the [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) library.  Unlike other drag-n-drop libraries, ng2-dnd doesn't manipulate the dom, and instead sends the object data to the dropped container.

Here is a link to their [online documentation](http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd).  The premise is pretty simple, and you do something like this:

(on the table you want to drag)

```
<tr *ngFor="let thing of things" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true" [dragData]=
"myDragData">
```

(on the table/div you want to drop)

```
<tbody dnd-droppable (onDropSuccess)="handleDrop($event)">
```